# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 at art::gc::Heap::GetObjectsAllocated()

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

Can anyone help to understand this trace?

```
09-16 17:18:32.684  25180-25192/? W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 30.520ms
09-16 17:18:32.686  25180-25192/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x550004 in tid 25192 (JDWP)
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1.1/LMY48M/2167285:user/release-keys'
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '11'
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 25180, tid: 25192, name: JDWP  >>> com.example.app <<<
09-16 17:18:32.788      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x550004
09-16 17:18:32.800      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 b4827800  r1 00000000  r2 4a5d70bd  r3 00550000
09-16 17:18:32.801      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 b483b39c  r5 00000002  r6 b483b3a0  r7 b3e721b0
09-16 17:18:32.803      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 b4889600  r9 01acd6d0  sl 02187db3  fp 00000000
09-16 17:18:32.804      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 00000045  sp b3e72198  lr b464ce7f  pc b462cbfe  cpsr 20070030
09-16 17:18:32.806      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
09-16 17:18:32.807      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 00137bfe  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::GetObjectsAllocated() const+25)
09-16 17:18:32.809      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 000f0871  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Dbg::DdmSendHeapInfo(art::Dbg::HpifWhen)+912)
09-16 17:18:32.810      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 000f0c37  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Dbg::DdmHandleHpifChunk(art::Dbg::HpifWhen)+114)
09-16 17:18:32.812      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 0001a5e9  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
09-16 17:18:33.226      185-185/? I/DEBUG﹕ Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
09-16 17:18:33.226      754-822/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-16 17:18:33.230      754-822/? W/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Dropping: SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE (10 > 0 bytes)
09-16 17:18:33.243    754-25262/? W/DropBoxManagerService﹕ Dropping: data_app_native_crash (1065 > 0 bytes)
09-16 17:18:33.255      199-199/? I/Zygote﹕ Process 25180 exited due to signal (11)
09-16 17:18:33.265      754-907/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.app (pid 25180) has died
09-16 17:18:33.265      754-907/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Scheduling restart of crashed service com.example.app/.service.Service in 4000ms
```

And is it possible to obtain more detailed stacktrace, to understand the problem? I've tried to get it by

```
adb pull /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 tomb.txt
```

command, but tombstone already deleted.

Comment: Did you find a reason of the problem?

Comment: nope. may be some bug in parse sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JDWP (Java Debug Wire Protocol) is reason of the problem. In my case, app doesn't crash if adb is disconnected.

Answer (score -2):

This is the Unix code for a **segmentation fault**. On Android, this is often caused by trying to use a not yet instanciated object. So look for places in your code where you might use an instance that is `null`.

Comment: Any way to find where it happens? May be which library or service do this?

Comment: @Anton There is the process id: `pid: 25180 `  It is probably the app you are testing anyway.

Comment: Yeah, bug in my app, i understand this. But i can't find end of a string, from which i can start working with problem.

Comment: @Anton Well I'm sure there is a way, but I don't know about it and I don't have time for any research this evening. Sorry :/

Comment: The posted stack trace says `fault addr 0x550004`, which is clearly not a null pointer dereference. It's failing in `libart.so`, apparently in response to a DDMS request, so it's unlikely this is a simple matter of the OP trying to use a null instance of something.

Comment: Ok, but i have no NullPointerException. How to obtain dump, or just longer trace, to see, what cause this? Because my logs ends on Handler.postDelayed with delay more than time delay before crash.